# Relative File Path in Blazor Server hosted on Site

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor server app (.net 6) that worked fine locally. I needed to load a configuration file for the Ebay api, so it is a YAML file kept in the structure of my project.

On the server I can hard code access to it with the following path and the site works perfectly:
$"D:/home/site/wwwroot/Config/ebay-config.yaml"

However, when I try to get the exact same result using the relative path method for blazor server I am screwing it up somehow.
$"wwwroot/Config/ebay-config.yaml"

That was the first thing I found and tried. It gives me an error that it can't find $"D:/home/site/**wwwroot/wwwroot**/Config/ebay-config.yaml". Clearly the relative file path works to an extent, but for some reason wwwroot is put in there twice and it fails.

Using $"{env.WebRootPath}/Config/ebay-config.yaml" gave a similar result, with two wwwroots.

Can someone please tell me what the correct method to use to get to the wwwroot folder from the web server? It is currently hosted on Azure if that matters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The default root for static files in Blazor is wwwroot, so don't specify wwwroot in your relative path.

Comment: That is the very first thing I had that worked locally but failed once I published it to Azure.

Comment: So using `$"wwwroot/Config/ebay-config.yaml"` gives you a path with `wwwroot` duplicated, but using `$"Config/ebay-config.yaml"` doesn't work, either? What path is the latter resulting in?

Comment: I will have to get home to get the exact path but I think if I put config like that I ended up with wwwrootconfig/file. Then as soon as I put the / in front of config it truncated off the front of the path and I it told me it couldn’t find D:/Config/file

Comment: Well, I'm an idiot. $"Config/ebay-config.yaml" works perfectly, so apparently I had typed it in wrong somehow. At this point I'm not even sure what I had. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else comes looking...

Per the comment from Lex I went back and looked at it again. Using the file locationg like this works on both localhost and azure server.

```
$"Config/ebay-config.yaml"
```